How to open custom url from New Teams Desktop app
In the old classic Desktop Teams app I had the below code to open a custom URL.
window.open('mydev://record?DB=7&URI=1', '_blank', 'noopener noreferrer');
This will redirect to the default browser and ask to open the URL in the installed app.
After switching to new Teams it is not working for Desktop teams.

This behavior is by design. We do not allow apps to open windows in the Teams Desktop Client (both in T1 and T2.1) to protect our users from spoofing attacks.
Any calls to window.open are blocked and the specified URL is launched in the user's default browser. We cannot provide a handle to the browser window since that runs in a completely different process.

Is this possible to redirect custom URL to browser from desktop team ?
This is my custom URL. "mydev://record".  ON button click is it possible to redirect to browser ?
